# Как лушче проверить пустой объект или имеет какие-то свойства?

Tags: javascript

Можно-ли использовать такую конструкцию, чтобы проверить, что в объекте есть перечислимые свойства? Или есть вариант лучше?

```
if( Object.keys( SomeObject ).length > 0 )
{
   return "Объект SomeObject имеет свойства";
} else 
{
    return "Объект SomeObject не имеет перечислимых свойств";
}
```

Comment: да вроде все правильно.... с помощью библиотек было бы короче... но на чистом js - так

Comment: да тока че то не работает =)

Comment: Все поправил вызов надо было Object.keys( SomeObject ).length

Comment: а я и не заметил)) я изначально так и прочитал :D